# Azure and JDBC - output specific Database entry

Tags: java, database, azure

i am working on a little Java project, where i have a little Database for Books, like a little virtual libraray.
Therefore i store the Data on an Microsoft Azure SQL Database.
I've read the documentation for JDBC and Azure from Microsoft. To read the Database, the following code is used:

```
    private static books readData(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    log.info("Read data");
    PreparedStatement readStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM books;");
    ResultSet resultSet = readStatement.executeQuery();
    if (!resultSet.next()) {
        log.info("There is no data in the database!");
        return null;
    }
    books book = new books();
    book.setisbn(resultSet.getString("isbn"));        
    book.setDetails(resultSet.getString("Title"));
    book.setA_vorname(resultSet.getString("AFirstname"));
    book.setA_nachname(resultSet.getString("ALastname"));
    book.setRelease(resultSet.getInt("release"));
    book.setGenre(resultSet.getString("Genre"));
    book.setBeschreibung(resultSet.getString("description"));        
    book.setDone(resultSet.getBoolean("done"));
    log.info("Data read from the database: " + book.toString());
    return book;
```

Now i want to display specific entrys from the DB, like a Book with a specific title or specific isbn, also books with one genre.
The code above just outputs the first entry in the DB.
I am still new in the field of databases and JDBC.
Does anyone know how I can read certain elements from the Azure database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [WHERE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clause in sql

```
PreparedStatement readStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM books WHERE book_name = ?;");
readStatement.setString(1, "Book name");
ResultSet resultSet = readStatement.executeQuery();
```